# Load files in assets folder through nanoHTTPD server

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to load files in assets folder in chrome custom tabs. For this, I am creating a HTTP server using NanoHTTPD. However, I am not able to load the files in assets folder. This is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.webar;

import ...


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button loadbtn = findViewById(R.id.loadbtn);
        final int port = 8000;

        final Server server = new Server(port);

        loadbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    server.start();
                    final CustomTabsIntent ctab = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();
                    String url = "http:/localhost:"+server.getListeningPort()+"/";
                    System.out.println("-------"+server.getHostname());
                    ctab.launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(url));
                }
                catch (IOException ioe){
                    System.out.println("-------Server didn't start");
                    server.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }}


 class Server extends NanoHTTPD {

    public Server(int port) {
        super(port);
    }
    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String uri = session.getUri();

        if (uri.equals("/")) {
            try {
                String path = "assets/index.html";
                File file = new File(path);
                System.out.println("---------"+file.exists());
                FileInputStream index = new FileInputStream(path);
                return newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK,MIME_HTML, index);
            }
             catch (FileNotFoundException fe){
                System.out.println("------File Not found");
            }
        }
        return  null;
    }
}
```

I have already tried the path file:///android_assets/index.html (which worked with web view), but doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an InputStream.

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("login.htm");
```

Then in src/main/assets I have

```
/css
/fonts
/img
/js
login.htm
logout.htm
```

Complete [nanohttpd example here.](https://github.com/Nuvolect/DeepDive-Android/blob/master/deepdive/src/main/java/com/nuvolect/deepdive/webserver/NanoHTTPD.java)